# Add spinner in YTPlayerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I want to add a spinner in `YTPlayerView`. I got merged commit of the code which does it.

https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/blob/master/Classes/YTPlayerView.m

But the problem is that it is a delegate method in which a view has to be returned. I don't know how to use the method.

```
  - (nullable UIView *)playerViewPreferredInitialLoadingView:(nonnull YTPlayerView *)playerView
```

Comment: see this once it helps you https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/48

Comment: Thank you,I will check it out.

Comment: Its working. But I had to add  `playerViewDidBecomeReady:(YTPlayerView *)playerView` to remove the indicator.

Comment: In the solution `- (void)playerView:(YTPlayerView *)playerView didChangeToState:(YTPlayerState)state` method is used. But it will not be called when the youtube view becomes ready. So I used the above method.

Comment: now ur problm is resolved bro

Comment: Yes, it is resolved. Thank you.

Comment: happy to hear bro,